# Types of laptop keypads connectors and compatibility

Tags: laptop, keyboard, netbook

I have a Samsung N150 Plus netbook with a misbehaving keyboard repeating keys, mostly the return key. In order to test whether the keyboard is faulty, I remove a keypad from another HP laptop and tried to connect it to the Samsung netbook.

Then I realised that the 2 connectors does not seem to fit each other. The HP keyboard ribbon width is slightly smaller than the samsung connector.

I want to test if the samsung keyboard is faulty first before I buy a new one. But how many types of keyboard connectors are there? Even if the connector is the same size, are all keyboard manufactured the same with regards to electric circuitry so that I can reliably test all the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can assume is that there is one type of connector and circuit layout *per model of laptop* (even though this isn't strictly true). You can't even assume that there is or isn't a controller (or even what type) directly in the keyboard circuitry, so you can't test it without knowing what a service technician for the manufacturer would.